# ?: and ?? Operators with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Why these operators does not work within these examples?

```
person.CityName = personInfo.Cities.CityName ?? "-";
```

or

```
person.CityName = personInfo.Cities.CityName == null ? "-" : personInfo.Cities.CityName;
```

View generates System.NullReferenceException. If they are not allowed what do you advice?

Comment: Did you consider that `Cities` can _also_ be null?

Comment: Cities Table has values. There is a foreign key between Cities and Person table. Just CityID in Person table is null.

Comment: So what is the value of `Cities` if the CityID in person table is null?

Comment: I don't understand. If there is a foreign key, can't i put null value in Person table. Must i put a value that exists in Cities table?

Comment: Ok i got it. I should control personInfo.Cities not personInfo.Cities.CityName. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

If the CityName column is nullable, you should check its `HasValue` property as follows. And if you like, you can also check if either `personInfo` or `personInfo.Cities` is null.

```
person.CityName = personInfo != null 
                  && personInfo.Cities != null 
                  && personInfo.Cities.CityName.HasValue 
                  ? personInfo.Cities.CityName.Value : "-";
```